# Enabling Implicit Context Variables Resolution for Apache Velocity macro parameters within Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, velocity

I find the Intellij implicit context variables invaluable when creating Apache Velocity templates.

For example:

```
#* @vtlvariable name="order" type="com.mycompany.vo.PlacedOrderVO" *#
#* @vtlvariable name="formatHelper" type="com.mycompany.FormatHelper" *#
#* @vtlvariable name="i18n" type="com.mycompany.I18nWriter" *#
```

However, I cannot figure a way to provide context for macro variables.  Does anyone know of a way?

The question was originally posed here:
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/08/enabling-implicit-context-variables-resolution-in-template-files/

Intellij suggests creating a file level definition like normal velocity variables, however the editor doesn't apply the contact variables to macro variables and I still get yellow warnings within my macros.

I would also consider suppressing the few warnings I do get within my macros, but Intellij does not give the option for statement level suppression within a macro, only file-wide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how this feature worked several years ago when you’ve asked, but currently (IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.1) it seems to be working.

```
#* @vtlvariable name="list" type="java.util.List" *#
#macro( disabled $list ) #if($list.isEmpty()) disabled #end #end
```

[image]